# Joke ways to say hello and goodbye, like "see you later alligator"

Tags: salutations

For those unfamiliar with "see you later aligator" see here: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=See%20you%20later%2C%20alligator.

Do you have some examples of rhyming greetings in French?

Comment: +1 for the question. I edited it to provide a link for those unfamiliar with the meaning of the idiom and its etymology. In addition, I corrected one spelling mistake. (Languages in English require capitalization unlike in French; that is, in French but en français, in English en anglais and so on.) Also, usually, there is no need for please, thanks and the like when you ask a question:-)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For now, but I promise I will add more if they come to my mind, here are some of the best... or worst, depends on the point of view:

There are three of a kind:

> À plus dans l'bus
> See you later in the bus
>
> À bientôt dans le métro
> See you later in the subway
>
> À demain dans le train
> See you tomorrow in the train

Note that *l'bus*, in the first one, is a contraction to keep the rhythm of the sentence but that is not grammatically correct.

<sup>*Source for those: https://www.elle.fr/Love-Sexe/Mon-mec-et-moi/Articles/Les-expressions-tue-l-amour-2701522*</sup>

---

This one doesn't rhyme but is silly enough to be here:

> À demain, à deux pieds
> See you tomorrow, on two feet

This is just a pun of language and cannot really be translated, it is a pun based on the fact that *demain* sounds exactly as *deux mains*; so *two hands*. Two hands, two feet; the pun is just based on this.

Another one from the same barrel:

> Allô, à l'huile
> Hello, in oil

Also just a pun of language based, again on the fact that *allô* (a greeting you would only use on the phone with someone), sounds exactly like *à l'eau*, so *in the water*... Once again, water, oil are two liquids, so they are associated in the pun.

<sup>*Source for those two: https://www.lefigaro.fr/langue-francaise/actu-des-mots/2016/12/28/37002-20161228ARTFIG00002-dix-expressions-a-eradiquer-en-2017.php*</sup>

---

One that does not rhyme, but has the same amount of syllables in the two part of the sentence:

> Si on se voit plus, on met des lunettes
> If we don't see each other anymore, let's put some glasses on

I have to confess that I have no clue where this one is coming from but seems to be a pun based on the fact that words to say goodbye like *au revoir*, are implying that we have to be able to see in order to see each other ever again, and that, if we don't, then, maybe it is just that we don't see clear enough anymore.

Comment: "Not grammatically correct" is kind of a misleading statement given the fact *dans l'bus* is how 99.sth % of native French speakers pronounce *dans le bus* in the real life.

Comment: @jlliagre agreed :) Still the rule only allows elision of le/la when followed by a consonants or a muted h.

Comment: Yes. I understand what you mean. The rule states that this *e* is required to be written in academic French. Hopefully, there is no rule that enforce that *e* to be pronounced. People are free to do it or not. In any case, both *dans le bus* and *dans l'bus* are correct ways to transcribe this spoken expression. By the way, it is certainly less that 99.sth % because this ellipsis is much less common in Southern France.

Comment: À plus tard dans le car? :)

Comment: A plus, ma puce !

Comment: À plus dans l’bus. By far the best one. xD

Comment: La classe à Dallas is quite good too but means something else

Comment: @Mat, this said, *"Salut, je m'casse à Dallas"* could be one ;)